# Find the Sum of the following series :

Tags: sequences-and-series

the question:

> Find the sum of the sequence $0.\bar{1}+0.0\bar{2}++0.00\bar{3}+\cdots
>  \forall$
>
> $ (A) \,\,0.1234 \dots \quad \quad(B)\,\,100/729  \quad\quad(C)\,\,100/99 
>   \quad\quad(D) \,\,\text{ none of these}.$

I found out it is an AGP (Arithmetic Geometric Progression), but I can't find how to calculate the infinite sum.

..any help is appreciated...

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are we to assume that the $n$th term of the series is $\frac {n}{9 \cdot 10^{n-1}}$?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetico%E2%80%93geometric_sequence

Comment: A is clearly too small ($0.\bar{1}+0.0\bar{2}>0.13$) and C clearly too big

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't really explicitly defined the pattern, as it is not clear what the terms of the series look like when we reach more than $1$ digit. But assuming that it follows the below pattern,

Recall that $0.\overline{x}=\frac{x}{9}$ for some digit $x$. Hence, the expression is equal to
$$\frac{1}{9}+\frac{2}{90}+\frac{3}{900}+\ldots+\frac{n}{9\cdot 10^{n-1}}+\ldots$$
$$\frac{1}{9}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{10^{n-1}}$$

Consider the infinite geometric series for $|x|<1$
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n=\frac{x}{1-x}$$
Taking the derivative of all sides gives
$$f'(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^{n-1}=\frac{1-x+x}{(1-x)^2}$$
$$f'(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^{n-1}=\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$$
Plugging in $x=\frac{1}{10}$, gives
$$f'(\frac{1}{10})=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{10^{n-1}}=\frac{1}{(1-\frac{1}{10})^2}$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{10^{n-1}}=\frac{100}{81}$$
Hence,
$$\frac{1}{9}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{10^{n-1}}=\boxed{\frac{100}{729}}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 0):

Usually the first step in solving this kind of problem is to figure out the pattern like the following:

$$
\frac{1}{9}\sum_{k\in\mathbb{N}}{k\cdot\left(\frac{1}{10}\right)^{k-1}}
$$

Look at the $k$ and $k-1$, remind you of derivative?

Answer (score 0):

Let $$S= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{9 \cdot 10^{n-1}}.$$

Then subtract the geometric series from each term and what's left will look awfully familiar: $S- \frac 19 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 10^{-n}= \frac{S}{10},$ so $\frac {9}{10}S = \frac 19 \frac {10}{9}= \frac{10}{81}$ and $S= \frac{100}{729}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot !!